# need help to understand a function in r

Tags: r

I am trying to understand a function in R. could you please declare some part of it for me:

the function is:

```
subsignals <- lapply(c(peakind$freqindex, midindex+1), function(x){
upperind <- x
fsub <- f
notnullind <- ((fsub$freqindex >= lowerind
                & fsub$freqindex < upperind)
               |
                (fsub$freqindex >  (lindex - upperind + 2)
                 & fsub$freqindex <= (lindex - lowerind + 2)))
fsub[!notnullind,"coef"] <- 0
lowerind <<- upperind
Re(fft(fsub$coef, inverse=TRUE)/length(fsub$coef))
})
```

Could some one explain me:

1-What could be the content of `notnullind` and generally, what does this part of code do:

```
notnullind <- ((fsub$freqindex >= lowerind
                & fsub$freqindex < upperind)
               |
                (fsub$freqindex >  (lindex - upperind + 2)
                 & fsub$freqindex <= (lindex - lowerind + 2)))
```

2-What does `fsub[!notnullind,"coef"] <- 0` mean?

3-What does`<<-` in `lowerind <<- upperind` mean?

further information:
`peakind` looks like this:

```
               coef freqindex
9   2.714391+3.327237i         9
17  1.273340+4.023808i        17
25 -0.445424+5.674848i        25
33 -1.378107+3.182281i        33
41 -2.798383+2.340895i        41
49 -4.479888+1.095193i        49
```

and `fsub` :

```
                     coef freqindex
1   19.2352397+0.0000000i         1
2   -0.4799684+0.1651822i         2
3    1.5235726+0.0790459i         3
4   -0.1165587+0.1217513i         4
5    2.2376900+1.6763410i         5
6    1.1256711+0.4624819i         6
.....
102 -0.1165587-0.1217513i       102
103  1.5235726-0.0790459i       103
104 -0.4799684-0.1651822i       104
```

Comment: `<<-` is normally used for global assignment of variables. You can look at `?"<<-" for further information.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the code is iterating through `fsub` in chunks defined by the difference between adjacent entries in `peakind`.  Presumably `peakind` contains interesting points in `fsub`.  You can see this because most of the `fsub` comparison are between `x` (which comes from `peakind`), and `lowerind`, which is set to be the prior loops `x`/`upperind` value.

1. `notnullind` will be a logical vector (TRUE, FALSE) that is TRUE for the rows in `fsub` that are between this iterations `peakind$freqindex` and the prior ones as well as something else based on `lindex` that I can't tell you b/c that variable is undefined in your code.
2. That line is setting all the values in `fsub$coef` that don't meet the condition described above to zero
3. `lowerind<<-upperind` is a global assignment outside of the function being run through `lapply`.  This allows the function run by `lapply` to keep track of the last `upperind` from a previous call to that same function in `lapply` loop.  The assignment must be global as otherwise the value would be lost after every iteration in `lapply`.

Basically, the function is doing an `fft` for the data between in `fsub` between adjacent pairs of index values defined in `peakind`.

Note that 3. suggests your function isn't structured in the best possible manner.  You should generally avoid global assignments unless you really can't.  In this case, I would loop through the rows of `cbind(head(peakind$freqindex, -1L), tail(peakind$freqindex, -1L))` which contains the range of indices you care about for each iteration.